# Could you please define the words contributors and span in the following text in a very very simple English

Tags: word-meaning

> History of medicine and their use:
>   Plants  have been collected cultivated harvested for the healing properties and used for the treatment of illness for centuries. **Contributors** to the current knowledge about drugs **span** the globe.

Please don't simplify whole passage. I need a simplified definition of the highlighted words so that I could research about the meaning of passage on my own.  A million thanks in advance.
I looked them up in the dictionaries but didn't manage to associate them with this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Contributors](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contributors?s=t): definition 1: people who add to something (in this case knowledge).

[Span](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/span?s=t): See definition 13; it means to extend everywhere. "Span the globe" means they are from all around the world.

Answer (score 2):

**Contributors** (noun, plural)

People who add to a collection, especially to increase the collection's size, or improve its value.

In this case, the text is likely referring to doctors, nurses, healers.

**Span** (verb)

To extend across a distance or area. To fully cover the distance.

In other usage, "span" can be a noun, meaning distance, length, magnitude, or even an object such as a beam, bridge or girder.